# .NET developer looking to branch out to Android, Do you have any tips and resources for me?

Tags: c#, android, .net, wpf

I am currently and for the past 3 years have been a .NET developer working on WPF and Siverlight and I want now to start learning how to be a developer for the Android OS. What should I start learning first, will my knowledge of .NET and C# help me or hurt me in this switch.

Please share your personal tips, online resources/web sites, books etc. that I should be aware of will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is not sharing/ advice site. asked such a questions in some other social sites.

Comment: @MD Oh come on! At least there is a part of it not sharing/advice. He asked if his knowledge of .NET and C# help me or hurt me in this switch!

Comment: @MD I don't see how sharing and advice is not in the sites core functionality but ok.

Comment: @SubzeroSC [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261068/should-i-be-asking-for-general-advice-on-stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261068/should-i-be-asking-for-general-advice-on-stackoverflow). check the answer.

Comment: @Sweeper [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261068/should-i-be-asking-for-general-advice-on-stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261068/should-i-be-asking-for-general-advice-on-stackoverflow). check the answer

Comment: Live and and learn I guess. @MD Thank you for the information about the guide lines and thank you for the way you approached giving me this information, that was awesome keep up the "good" work.

Answer (score 1):

I was the same as you! I used to love C# and .NET and now I am doing some android stuff! Let me tell you more about it.

You develop Android apps using Java (as you might already know). Java's syntax is extremely similar to C# but without delegates and events. However, you can achieve those by using interfaces.

The first book that I read about Android is *Programming in Java for Android Development for Dummies* by Barry A. Burd. Burd is a really good writer and I suggest that you can read his book. Although you might not like to read books that are for "dummies", I did it anyways.

Also, you need to write XML layout files for the layout (as you might already know). but I think you must have written a lot of XMLs in WPF so it's not a problem.

Furthermore, Stack Overflow is a really good website. You can find almost everything in here. You should also go to developers.android.com to read the docs.

Mostly what I've learned is by my "trial and error learning strategy". I just try some of this and some of that and then it works and I can learn from these experiences. I can do it and I'm only 14 so you certainly *can* do it as well.

And I think that's all I have to say, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you can use Xamarin to leverage your C# skills to an extent. Using Xamarin can be barrier to development in some cases (for example most code examples you'll find for Android will be in Java) but it's arguable that that could promote a more in depth learning experience as you'll have to write your code from scratch rather than copying and pasting.

I find using being able to use Visual Studio for Android dev is a great help, as we all know it's the best IDE :)

If you really want to learn Android development with the native tools, then you could consider Xamarin a stepping stone.

http://xamarin.com/

Comment: I tried Xamarin as well, but visual studio said that there are deployment errors and cannot start my app so that's why I develop apps in "The Normal Way", using Android Studio and java.

Comment: @Ian Newson Xamarin forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: @lan you are working in such a nice company. `xibis`

Comment: @javi I use Xamarin.Android, I've used forms before but for an iOS project.

Comment: @MD thanks! Yes it's a good company that I'm fortunate enough to help run.